# MySQL Error You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-delete

I have a 2 tables MST_customer and TRN_sales in my database with corrupt entries. The next query returns the corrupt entries:

```
SELECT TRN_sales.cust_no 
FROM MST_customer 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TRN_sales 
ON MST_customer.cust_no = TRN_sales.cust_no 
WHERE MST_customer.cust_name IS NULL;
```

I tried to delete them executing:

```
DELETE FROM mydbB.TRN_sales
WHERE TRN_sales.cust_no IN (
  SELECT TRN_sales.cust_no
  FROM MST_customer
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN TRN_sales
  ON MST_customer.cust_no = TRN_sales.cust_no
  WHERE MST_customer.cust_name IS NULL
);
```

But I get the next error:

```
You can't specify target table 'TRN_sales' for update in FROM clause
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a bit more on "the safe side" you should specifiy the table (here: alias name `s`) you want to delete from like:

```
DELETE s FROM TRN_sales s
LEFT JOIN MST_customers ON MST.cust_no=TRN.cust_no
WHERE MST.cust_name IS NULL;
```

Personnaly I believe, this `LEFT JOIN` is easier to read, although of course you can do the same with your `RIGHT JOIN` version.

Comment: @cars10: May you elaborate how "delete s" is more safe than "delete TRN.*".....yes left join is more readbale but I just worked on Rin's query so that he feel easy as it was same like as his query...but there is no issue in both if you use left join or right join.

Comment: Hi Zafar, your answer is (and always was) 100% correct! When I wrote my answer I misread your `TRN.*` as referring to the whole db. That was not the case, as you quite rightly only refer to the sales table in question. So from my point of view your answer is still the correct one and deserves to be the "chosen one" as it appeared first here. The only reason I kept my answer was to show an alternative way with `LEFT JOIN` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`. I just 'upped' your post anyway... ;-)

Comment: @cars10: No not at all, I was just curious if there is any major impact of alias.* and just alias in deletion under join. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't try below-

```
DELETE TRN.*
FROM MST_customer MST
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TRN_sales TRN
ON MST.cust_no = TRN.cust_no 
WHERE MST.cust_name IS NULL;
```

Note: For safe side keep backup of both tables before executing this query.

Comment: You do not need the `*`: `DELETE TRN FROM ...` will also work.